# If 1000 people randomly select an integer between 1 and 200 (inclusive) . . .

Tags: probability

Calculate the probability that precisely four of those people select the number 105?

Could it possibly be:

$(\frac{1}{200})^4 \cdot( 1-\frac{1}{500})^{(1000-4)} $?

Comment: Two errors: 1.  The fraction $\frac{1}{500}$ should be $\frac{1}{200}$.  2.  You need to multiply by the binomial coefficient $\binom{200}{4}$, which gives the number of groups of four people (order unimportant) selected from $200$.  What you have there (once the first error is corrected) is the probability that a *given* set of four people pick $105$, while everyone else picks another number.

Comment: The first error was just a simple mistype. Thank you for your corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that pn shows the nth person's selection, one of the possible situation 
is

$${p1=200, p2=200, p3=200, p4=200, p5\neq200, ..., p1000 \neq 200 }$$

The probability of the above event is $$(\frac{1}{200})^4(1-\frac{1}{200})^{1000-4}$$

However we can select the four people arbitrarily. The total number of selection is given by $\binom{1000}{4}$. Then the total probability becomes

$$\binom{1000}{4}(\frac{1}{200})^4(1-\frac{1}{200})^{1000-4}$$

Regards,